# How to implement a switch here instead of if's and else if's?

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I’m using if/else statements to check which radio button is clicked. How to use a switch statement instead of if/else.

```
else if (CBLeather.Checked && CBComputerNav.Checked && !CBStereo.Checked) {
    accessories = Accessories.LeatherAndNavigation;
} else if (CBComputerNav.Checked && CBLeather.Checked && CBStereo.Checked) {
    accessories = Accessories.All;
} else {
    accessories = Accessories.None;
}
```

Comment: Very complicatedly. If you’ve handled the enum correctly you could use or statements but it’s not shown

Comment: I'd suggest keeping the if statements. Switch isn't really designed for this use case.

Comment: Why do you want a switch statement?

Comment: I couldn't show all my code because It asked me to describe it but I couldn't but since it saw less code SO was ok with it

Comment: A switch statement doesn't help you here. Extract the conditions into variables to make it more readable.

Comment: I need it because it's cleaner and more efficient...

Comment: A switch statement typically acts on a single value. Here you have 3 different values. It seems like a switch statement ought to make this _more complicated_. Also, beware premature optimisation.

Comment: First, this is more "code review" than "practical programming problem", hence off-topic for Stack Overflow, or at best "too broad". Second, as noted, there's no reason to believe a `switch` would be an improvement. Third, you could at least consolidate the `CBLeather.Checked && CBComputerNav.Checked` test, since that's in the first two `if` expressions. Fourth, since you are dealing with flags, it is _possible_ there's a reasonable way to consider those as bits in an index, and have an array of values it maps to. But you didn't provide enough context for it to be possible to know.

Comment: @John and everyone else thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot put switch case here i think as you have multiple condition for code branching.

You can extract methods from these conditions and just call them in your if blocks something like:

```
private bool IsLeatherAndNavigation()
{
   return CBLeather.Checked && CBComputerNav.Checked && !CBStereo.Checked;
}
```

and use :

```
if (IsLeatherAndNavigation()) 
{
   accessories = Accessories.LeatherAndNavigation;
}
```

and can be reused wherever required instead of putting the duplicated if conditions everywhere around in the class.

Answer (score 0):

Although your use case is not meant for a switch statement but there is a crazy way of doing so :)

```
switch (0)
{
    case 0 when (CBLeather.Checked && CBComputerNav.Checked && !CBStereo.Checked):
        accessories = Accessories.LeatherAndNavigation;
        break;
    case 0 when (CBComputerNav.Checked && CBLeather.Checked && CBStereo.Checked):
        accessories = Accessories.All;
        break;
    default:
        accessories = Accessories.None;
        break;
}
```

Again, it works but not advisable!